# Change attached Toolbar to another Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

So I already set a Toolbar (which is already attached to my activity xml) as the Action Bar. And now I want to change that Toolbar to another Toolbar. How to do this?

This is what I've tried, but doesn't work:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_category, null);   
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ab_spinner);
SpinnerAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fonts, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

toolbar_category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:elevation="4dp" >

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/ab_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by i want to change that ToolBar to another toolBar?

Comment: well, I have 2 Toolbar xml (for example one with TextView, and another with Spinner, and suppose both have different color). I already set one toolbar as the action bar, but now when I open a certain fragment, I want to change the previous attached Toolbar with another Toolbar from my another Toolbar xml.

Comment: Same problem, searching for solution. In my case, the toolbar that I set is placed below current toolbar. I don't know why and what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to set toolbar for your activity.

```
protected Toolbar getActionBarToolbar() {
    if (toolbar == null) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.YOURSECONDTOOLBAR);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }
    return toolbar;
}
```